# Convert phone number 999-999-9999 to (999)999-9999

Tags: apex

I have a list of contacts with phone numbers in the form of 999-999-9999. They are to be displayed in the form of (999)999-9999. Can Anyone suggest a pseudo apex code for this

Answer (score 1):

```
string S = '999-999-9999';
S='(' + (S.replaceFirst('-', ')'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static String formatphonenum (String s) {
s = '(' + s.substring(0, 3) + ') ' + s.substring(6)    + '-' + s.substring(6);
  return s;
  }
```